# ARKit - Resize object along particular direction

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to resize an object along a specific direction in ARKit.
For example, there is a cube on a detected plane and I want to be able to resize the cube in X direction, Y direction and Z direction respectively. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Resizing virtual objects is not ARKit's job, but actually the renderer job (e.g., SceneKit, Metal, etc.). Do you know what renderer are you using? If you are not sure, you can post the part of the code that adds the cube to the scene.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replying. I am using SceneKit. Here is the example what I want to do for my project: https://youtu.be/rwi1THNleeM  Basically it is a measuring box to measure the size of the object but I need to be able to resize each side of the cube individually just like the demo in the video.

Comment: I see, what you want is a bounding box. I suggest that you take a look at [Scanning and Detecting 3D Objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) sample code. There's much more than what you're asking, but there's also code for a bounding box.